# Segment in GA4 Excluding Email is not Working When Report is Split by Medium

Tags: google-analytics-4, segment

I've built a segment in Google Analytics 4 (GA4) to exclude sessions coming in through Email as a medium. I've run a report for sessions for that exact dimension, but Email is coming through. Has anyone else encountered this with GA4? I never had this problem with UA, but am I building the segment wrong?

When I create the segment:

- I choose Session Based
- Don't include anything in the Include section
- In Exclusions, I set Medium **exactly matches** Email

When I create the explore

- I put sessions in metrics
- Medium in Rows
- The newly created segment in my segments

Email will appear as one of the mediums that is receiving sessions. I have switched between setting the exclusion temporary v permanent and get the same results.